# Getting ngModel value in controller - AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

The player's name is alerted once submitPlayer is clicked, and I want the corresponding player id too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
     <input id="search" class="search nomargin" type="text" class="validate dark" ng-model="player">
     <label for="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search Player</label>
   </div>
 </div>

     <div class="searchresultsbox z-depth-1">
       <div class="row nopad nomargin">
     <div class="col s12 nopad nomargin">
           <ul ng-repeat="eachPlayer in player |filter:search">
             <li>{{eachPlayer.name}}</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>

<div class="modalbuttongroup">
    <a href="" class="center waves-effect waves-light btn addplayer" ng-click="submitPlayer()">ADD PLAYER</a>
</div>
```

**Module and Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('playerapp', []);

app.controller("myController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.player=

    [
         {
          "id": "57f2ade2d9913939d0de4af8",
          "name": "A Team Player"

         },
         {
          "id": "57f3d03fd99139333880a2f8",
          "name": "B Team Player"
         },
         {
          "id": "57f3d05ad99139333880a2fa",
          "name": "C Team Player"
         },
         {
          "id": "57f3fff6d991394b3daa2d49",
          "name": "D Team Player"
         },
         {
          "id": "57f422d6d991390ea392762e",
          "name": "E Team Player"
         }
    ]

    $scope.submitPlayer = function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.player,null,5))
    };
});
```

Also, I want the player name to be displayed in the textfield once the player is selected and and when clicking 'add player' I want the player ID to be alerted.

Comment: what you are describing doesn't exactly match with the UI you designed here.  You have a search box, followed by a table, followed by a submit button.  If you hit the submit button, the alert is going to show the entire array.  If you are only getting a single item, it is because your search limited your array to one element.  But even that doesn't make sense, because your search field isn't set up correctly, either.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code,

(i) You are using player as a search value which is a collection, so it should be changed.

```
  <input id="search" class="search nomargin" type="text" class="validate dark" ng-model="player.name">
```

and used as a filter,

```
<ul ng-repeat="eachPlayer in player |filter:player.name">
```

And there is no way to select player with your html code, so i have added a radio input button to select player and assign to a scope variable.

```
  <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="rdbRisk" ng-change="Assign(selected)" ng-value="eachPlayer" /> {{eachPlayer.name}}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/YPrg3ClCKUybzxa6xkUD?p=preview)**

Comment: In materilaize its not Sir

Comment: check the demo aravi

Comment: yes demo working but when we integrate in materilaize it wont work

Comment: @AraviS that you need to sort it out, upvote if it has helped

Comment: you are done in html way rit?.Please check cdn script of materilaize inside it, it wont work

Comment: @AraviS modify the plunker and attach the link i will check

Comment: <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: please add this script it wint work that radio btn not shown up

Comment: Sir check it. radi button and addplayer btn not working rit?

Comment: modify the plunker so that i can check

Comment: I have no permission to modify your code thats why i created new and I post that link pls chek it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125837/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-aravi-s).